# Unity: Why downloading a text asset from internet doesn't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, unity-networking, unitywebrequest

I tried to use a coroutine to download a get a text by `UnityWebRequest.Get(url);`

In the NetworkManager Class, I have these two exactly identical Coroutines but in different name:

```cs
public static IEnumerator DownloadTextCoroutine(string url, Action<string> callback)
    {
        List<word> newList = new List<word>();
        UnityWebRequest web = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return web.SendWebRequest();

        if (web.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError(web.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string Unprocessed = web.downloadHandler.text;
            callback?.Invoke(Unprocessed);
        }
    }
```

In the GameManager Class, I tried to run the coroutine and pass the text assests requested to a method `initPlayerData(string A, string B)`, (i.e. this method is totally fine, so no worries about it). So In `awake()`, I run the coroutine. But it turns out the text assests are not downloaded.

```cs
 public void Awake()
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = this;
                DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }

            Debug.Log(FirstTimeChecking.checkIsFirstTime());

            if (FirstTimeChecking.checkIsFirstTime())
            {
                StartCoroutine(NetworkManager.DownloadTextCoroutine("https://xxx/words.txt", result =>
                {
                    words = result;
                    isWordsDownloaded = true;
                }));

                StartCoroutine(NetworkManager.DownloadIdiomCoroutine("https://xxx/idioms.txt", result =>
                {
                    idioms = result;
                    isIdiomsDownloaded = true;
                }));

                StartCoroutine(WaitForDownloads());
            }
            else
            {
                playerData = playerDataLoader.playerData;
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator WaitForDownloads()
        {
            // Wait until both downloads have completed
            while (!isWordsDownloaded || !isIdiomsDownloaded)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            // Run code after the downloads have completed
            initPlayerData(words, idioms);
        }
```

I expecct I can access 2 text assests and store them into a variable and pass it to  `initPlayerData(words, idioms);` and the game shall run well.

I have tried this way and other many ways. If I put the coroutine in `initPlayerData() [original]`, where there are some loops to handle the data, works. So I decided to seperate the Requesting Text process and the data process, i.e. `initPlayerData(words, idioms);`.

Thank you so much

Comment: Where is result set? I see you assigning stuff to its value but i dont see it getting set

Comment: The downloaded text format should be:
`
Apple,\tAffle
Orange,\tOmange
`

The variables `words` and `idioms` will be passed into `initPlayerData(string A, string B)`

The expected result should be:
storing into a list of word, i.e. `List<word>`

where, 

```
public class word{
    public string wordName;
    public bool isCorrect;

}
```

But now, with this code, this list is empty.

Comment: as I said.. where is result set? you have `words = result;`  but you dont show result being set

Comment: ` string Unprocessed = web.downloadHandler.text; ` the result set is downloaded from the site.  An example is { Apple,\tAffle Orange,\tOmange }

Comment: i dont think theres enough code to recreate it here,  some debug logs should show where it disappears from

Comment: After adding some Debug.Log() I have found the issue, thank you so much!